# I can not run a project I did not create

Tags: android-studio

I have been trying to run a project - which I did not create , but downloaded - in android studio.

For that matter, I put this project's folder in my android studio projects folder.
Then, I use an option of "import existing project". The project seems to be successfully imported. However, the option of run is not active , or disabled.
The same happens when I try the option of "open existing project" instead.

What is the reason for that problem, and how should it be resolved ?

Comment: Try synchronizing the project to check if the gradle used by the project matches with the gradle that you use. If not, you can download the [current version of the gradle.](https://gradle.org/install/#prerequisites) Hope it helps

Comment: @FQuouhadiho  well, I did. Still doesn't work...